# The method polygon(float[]) is undefined for the type ShapeRenderer

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to draw a polygon with shaperenderer in libgdx but it's come out with the following error :

> The method polygon(float[]) is undefined for the type ShapeRenderer

this is my code :

```
ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if(isbox)
        {
            renderer.begin(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            renderer.rect(defaultsettings.MeterToPixWidthScaling(position.x - (width/2)), defaultsettings.MeterToPixHeightScaling(position.y - (height/2)), defaultsettings.MeterToPixWidthScaling(width),defaultsettings.MeterToPixWidthScaling(height));
        }else{
            renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
            renderer.polygon(new float[] { -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 200 });
        }
        renderer.end();
```

Comment: Which version do you use? In the latest version/nightlies the method definetely exists.

Comment: @noone also in the Api (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.html) i can't see the `ShapeType.Rectangle`

Comment: no really there is no polygon i'm using version 0.98 i will try to use 0.99 but i really wonder how this is possible !